# How can we write $\dfrac{1}{(z-2)^2}$ as a powerseries around $z_0 = i$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

As per title, we have
\begin{align}
f(z) = \dfrac{1}{(z-2)^2}, \ z \neq 2.
\end{align}

We want to write this as a powerseries around $z_0 = i$ and find the radius of convergence.

It is already known that
\begin{align}
\dfrac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n, \ |x|<1.
\end{align}
Differentiating powerseries we can have
\begin{align}
-\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^2} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n x^{n-1}, \ |x|<1
\end{align}
how can we arrive at the conclusion over $i$?

The radius of convergence is known to be (if it exists)
\begin{align}
R:= \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{|c_n|}{|c_{n+1}|} \in [ 0, \infty ).
\end{align}

How can we proceed?

Comment: Do the change of variable $z=i+h$ and then $x=-\frac h{i-2}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\frac 1 {(z-2)^{2}}=\frac  1 {((z-i)+(i-2))^{2}}=\frac  1{(i-2)^{2}} \frac 1 {(1+(z-i)/(i-2))^{2}} $

Comment: OK good hint. I went:
\begin{align}
\dfrac{1}{(i-2)^2} \cdot \dfrac{1}{\left( 1 - \dfrac{i-z}{i-2} \right)^2} &= \dfrac{1}{(i-2)^2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \left( \dfrac{i-z}{i-2} \right)^{n-1}\\
&= \dfrac{1}{(i-2)(i-z)} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{n}{(2-i)^{n}} (z-i)^{n}
\end{align}
I think I forgot a minus somewhere, what do you think about it?

Comment: It is correct but you missed the minus sign when you used the formula for $-\frac 1  {(1-x)^{2}}$. @algevristis

Comment: Oh yes so the final answer is 
\begin{align}
\boxed{-}\dfrac{1}{(i-2)(i-z)} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{n}{(2-i)^n}(z-i)^n
\end{align}
and I also find the radius to be by using the limit above $R = 2-i$, can such a radius exist? Given that it is supposed to be a number in $[0,+\infty)$

Comment: The radius is determined by the condition $|\frac {-i-z} {i-2}| <1$ or $|i-z|<\sqrt 5$, So the radius is $\sqrt 5$. @algevristis

Comment: How can that be proven by taking the above limit (which by the way is the one the exercise calls me to use)

Comment: @algevristis I am just using the fact that the differentiated series $\sum nx^{n-1}$ has radius $1$.

Comment: Even still, you wrote 
\begin{align}
|\dfrac{-i-z}{i-2}|
\end{align}
how does that pop up?

Comment: That was  a typo. I meant $|\frac {i-z}{i-2}| <1$@algevristis

Comment: So what's the correct answer? 

$|\dfrac{n}{(2-i)^n}| < 1?$

Comment: My main problem is that even by that approach we get that 
\begin{align}
R = (2(1-i), 2)
\end{align}
and I have the feeling that it's not acceptable to have $i$ as a number in radius.

Comment: TUrns out you do not have to have the minus in, since
\begin{align}
\left( \dfrac{1}{1-x} \right)' = -\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^2} \cdot (1-x)' = \dfrac{1}{(1-x)^2}
\end{align}